# Lucene: new WordnetSynonymParser(boolean dedup,boolean expand, Analyzer analyzer)

Tags: java, lucene, wordnet

Please, the constructor of **WordnetSynonymParser** accept three parameters:

```
boolean dedup, boolean expand and an Analyzer.
```

But, what is dedup and expand? I don't understand.

The documentation [cites](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/package-summary.html):

> If dedup is true then identical rules (same input, same output) will
>   be added only once.

which means? An example? And the parameter `expand`?

Help me, please... thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dedup` value is passed directly to the `SynonymMap.Builder`, and does as it says.  If two *identical* synonym rules exist, it only uses one of them.  It's probably pretty safe to set this to `true` unless you have reason not to.

to understand `expand`, here's how it is used:

```
 if (expand) {
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
       add(synset[i], synset[j], false);
     }
   }
 } else {
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     add(synset[i], synset[0], false);
   }
 }
```

So, if expand is true, it adds a synonym to the resulting set for each possible combination of synonyms in the set.  If it is false, it would create synonym rules such that each synonym would be replaced only with the first synonym in the list.  Say, if we had a set of synonymous words:  "`walk`", "`stroll`" and "`amble`"

Expanded, this would generate the synonyms:

```
walk -> walk
walk -> stroll
walk -> amble
stroll -> walk
stroll -> stroll
stroll -> amble
amble -> walk
amble -> stroll
amble -> amble
```

Without expanding, you would just have:

```
walk -> walk
stroll -> walk
amble -> walk
```

Generally, I would be inclined to set this to false, so that synonym matches get reduced to one main synonym, but it does depend on your needs.